# Deleting two items from doubly-linked list segfault

Tags: c, doubly-linked-list

I have a program using a doubly linked list and simplifies them.

NULL<-> [HEADPTR] <->[VALUEA, 1] <-> [ValueB, 2] <-> [ADD, VALUEA, VALUEB] <-> ...Rest of list

NULL <-> [VALUEC, 3] <-> ...Rest of list.

I am just confused on how I would delete both VALUEA & B. I can successfully delete on of the values, but when I try to delete both of them I get a segmentation fault. I know my logic for deleting the second node is wrong. I am using a three pointer system to find and simplify the values.

```
while(rightP->next != NULL){
            if(rightP->critical == 'Y'){
                //printf("Found a critial\n");
                //Critical helps me find what I need to merge
                        rightP->field2 = leftP->field2 + middleP->field2;
                        //printf("MERGING ADD %d\n", rightP->field2);
                        temp1 = leftP;
                        if(leftP->prev != NULL)
                            leftP = leftP->prev;
                        else
                            leftP->prev = NULL;
                        leftP->next = temp1->next;
                        leftP->next->prev = leftP;
                        free(temp1);
                        //bad segment
                        //Yields Seg fault
                        temp2 = middleP;
                        middleP->prev = leftP;
                        middleP->next = temp2->next;
                        middleP->next->prev = middleP;
                        middleP = rightP;
                        rightP = rightP->next;
                        free(temp2);
          }
          leftP = leftP->next;
          middleP = middleP->next;
          rightP = rightP->next;
          else{
                leftP = leftP->next;
                middleP = middleP->next;
                rightP = rightP->next;
          }
}
```

Comment: Can you please post a syntactically correct code?

Comment: You don't delete both A *and* B. You delete A. Then you delete B. Deleting B is no different to deleting A.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

years ago, i jotted down a note in my K&R ansi c book.
it was a *you cannot do this* regarding your use of `free(temp1);`

you did not post complete code, but your use of `temp1 = leftP` and then `free(temp1)` is almost exactly what I jotted down years ago saying can't do that.

Never figured the reason for that, it was based off of using `malloc()` or `calloc()` and then when using `free()` the argument to `free()` had to be the pointer used in the malloc or calloc statement.

suggest you re-use the temp pointer in a different way; then whatever pointer name *assuming* you used `malloc` then use that pointer and set it to the node you want to free... after adjusting the `->next` and `->previous` values to keep the list intact.

found it:

page 252, K&R The C Programming Language 2nd edition

`void free ( void *p )`

free deallocates the space pointed to by p; it does nothing if p is null. **p must be a pointer to space previously allocated by calloc, malloc, or realloc.**